# Universal property of the V-Mat construction

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories, universal-property, internal-categories

Internal categories and enriched categories can both be realised as monads in certain bicategories. If $\mathcal E$ is a category with pullbacks, then a monad in $\mathbf{Span}(\mathcal E)$ is a category internal to $\mathcal E$. If $\mathcal W$ is a locally cocomplete bicategory, then a monad in $\mathcal W\text{-}\mathbf{Mat}$ is a category enriched in $\mathcal W$. §2 of Cruttwell–Shulman's [A unified framework for generalized multicategories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2460) contains a nice introduction to these ideas.

It is known that $\mathcal E \to \mathbf{Span}(\mathcal E)$ [has a universal property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span#UniversalPropertyOfThe2CategoryOfSpans), given by adjoining right adjoints to morphisms in $\mathcal E$ subject to a Beck–Chevalley condition.

Assume for now that $\mathcal W$ is small. There is an identity-on-objects pseudofunctor $\mathbf{Set}/\mathbf{ob}(\mathcal W) \to \mathcal W\text{-}\mathbf{Mat}$ such that every morphism in the domain has a right adjoint in the codomain (see §1 of Betti–Carboni–Street–Walter's [Variation through enrichment](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404983901007), for instance). It therefore seems reasonable to expect that $\mathcal W\text{-}\mathbf{Mat}$ has a universal property analogous to that of $\mathbf{Span}(\mathcal E)$, but for which the Beck–Chevalley condition is replaced by a some other suitable condition.

Does $\mathcal W\text{-}\mathbf{Mat}$ have such a universal property?

---

In Remark 15.21 of Garner–Shulman's [Enriched categories as a free cocompletion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3191), they give a universal property of $\mathcal W\text{-}\mathbf{Mat}$ as a cocompletion of $\mathcal W$ under small $\mathbf{Coprod}$-enriched coproducts, which may be a starting point.

Comment: I think that [Garner and Shulman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3191) give some universal property for $\mathcal V-Mat$.

Comment: @TimCampion: thanks, I had just remembered that, came back to edit my question, and saw you had made the same observation :)

Comment: The objects of V-Mat are just sets, so I don't see your identity-on-objects pseudofunctor to it from $\rm Set/ob(V)$.

Comment: @MikeShulman: thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to deloop $\mathcal V$. I've modified the question to involve enrichment in a bicategory $\mathcal W$ to avoid that confusion.

Comment: Okay, now I see.  I can't imagine what such another "suitable condition" would look like: it would have to involve W somehow, since Set/ob(W) contains no information about W other than its set of objects (which is trivial in the case of BV), while all of W sits inside W-Mat.